# What well designed Icehouse games are available for two people?

Tags: recommendations, icehouse

Recently the [Icehouse game system](http://www.looneylabs.com/whybuy/treehouse.html) has caught my eye.  I've looked through a ton of rules on the [Icehouse Wiki](http://icehousegames.org/wiki/) but haven't found any really engaging game for two players.  What well designed Icehouse games are available for two people? The amount of stashes is not really and issue for me.  I'm looking for games that flow well, are not too complex, and are enjoyable for two players.

Comment: You might want to accept an answer for this question, if there's an answer that meets your needs. If not, I'd recommend asking for clarification in comments, or editing your question to be more specific, so people can edit their answers or write new ones that will better answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite 2-player Icehouse game is [Volcano](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13084/volcano), you need to print out one sheet of paper with the "board" (though you could still play without it), rules are simple but the game is quite deep in strategy. The game requires 6 stashes of different colors.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite two-player Icehouse games are [Volcano](http://icehousegames.org/wiki/index.php?title=Volcano) and [Binary Homeworlds](http://icehousegames.org/wiki/index.php?title=Binary_Homeworlds).

You can find a list of [2-player games](http://icehousegames.org/wiki/index.php?title=Category:2-player) on the Icehouse Wiki, but of course, that has tons of games of varying quality. You can find some of the best and most popular games on the [Existing Games](http://icehousegames.org/wiki/index.php?title=Existing_Games) page, which points out out games that have been published and games that have won competitions to help guide you to the games most likely to be good and well known.

Answer (score 3):

[Gnostica](http://icehousegames.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gnostica) is an excellent Icehouse game for two players, but it might fall foul of your "not too complex" restriction. The [Rules Reference](http://www.wunderland.com/icehouse/GnosticaRulesRef.pdf) helps, but even so, it's not really simple.

I'd highly recommend [Binary Homeworlds](http://icehousegames.org/wiki/index.php?title=Binary_Homeworlds). Although multiplayer Homeworlds has an explicit political element and some hidden information, the two-player version Binary Homeworlds loses those to become a pure-strategy game, with eminently simple rules, but astonishing depth.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite two-player icehouse games are [Zendo](http://www.koryheath.com/games/zendo/) and Volcano. Zendo is an excellent game for two players in two styles. The first is when competition isn't particularly difficult. Then the game is played normally and is functionally one person posing logic puzzles to the other. The second is the Dharma-duel which is an excellent way for both people to be "master"

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at my own game here:
http://pages.videotron.com/remneb/binary.html

Comment: Looks interesting.  I can almost comprehend the rules well enough to try it sometime.